# set min-height on div but make all divs same height

Tags: html, css

I am using this CSS code:

```
<style type="text/css">
html,body {
    font-family:Arial;
}
.container {
    text-align:center;
}
.box {
    width:350px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:10px 20px 0 auto;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    min-height:60px;
    font-size:60px;
    text-align: center;
}
.box h2 {
    font-size:40px;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

but i want the divs to all have the same height

i have created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UDm3a/

Comment: What's the point of min-height then? You want each div to have the height of the highest one but not below the min-height?

Comment: check here: http://jsfiddle.net/UDm3a/ - what happens if i do just height

Comment: I imagine he what's them to have a min-height in case they ALL are shorter than the required minimum. However, I'm not sure I see the  point either.

Comment: Oh, that's the problem, different offsets. Try putting `float: left;` on them. http://jsfiddle.net/UDm3a/2/

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible with CSS only and with your current markup.

Comment: works great but i want to keep everything in the centre and not to the left ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this jQuery trick:

```
$(function() {
  $.fn.setAllToMaxHeight = function(){
    return this.height(
      Math.max.apply(this, $.map(this, function(e) { return $(e).height() }) )
    )
  }

  $('div.box').setAllToMaxHeight();
  //setTimeout("$('div.box').setAllToMaxHeight();", 10);
});
```

And CSS add:

```
.box {
   width:350px;
   display: inline-block;
   margin:10px 20px 0 auto;
   padding:10px;
   border:1px solid black;
   min-height:60px;
   font-size:60px;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UDm3a/7/

Comment: That's the best way to go, IMHO. Even with CSS3 it's too tricky. Jquery to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Use height, instead of min-height. e.g.:

```
height: 220px;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the same offsets and heights, you need to float them and set the height.

```
float: left;
height: 300px;
```

Like the fiddle I gave you in the comments: http://jsfiddle.net/UDm3a/2/

The other option is to use `vertical-align: top;` along with height, so:

```
vertical-align: top;
height: 300px;
```

See that here: http://jsfiddle.net/UDm3a/3/

If you want to set the height dynamically, I'm afraid you'll have to use JavaScript to find the highest on and apply its height to the others.

Comment: This is not what OP is asking. Height should be flexible.

Comment: It doesn't say that, but I've covered that case as well - in the last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by decreasing the `font-size` and setting the `min-width` and `max-width` as same. Even though setting `min-height` might not be required but it worked for me.

```
CSS
html,body {
font-family:Arial;
}
.container {
text-align:center;
}
.box {
    display: inline-block;
padding:10px;
border:1px solid black;
text-align: center;
    font-size: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
}
.box h2 {
font-size:100%;
text-align:center;
}
```

You can see the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekverma3189/qvtWR/

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, then there are several methods to accomplish what you need.

you can find them here: [Fluid Width Equal Height Columns](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)

They solve the problem like this:

[image]

to be like this:

[image]

[you can see a **D E M O** here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/FluidEqualHeightFauxColumns/)

and you can download the source files from here: [DOWNLOAD FILES](http://css-tricks.com/examples/FluidEqualHeightFauxColumns.zip)